# How to get object property with counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reciving the formValues object, and when I console.log it, I get this result:

```
attribute_0: "2478"
attribute_1: "2475"
attribute_2: "2480"
```

What I need is to take those values and store it in a hidden input field, to have something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="2478,2475,2480">
```

And I could do it, but somehow I can't access this properties in a for loop, so not to do it like:

```
formValues.attribute_0;
formValues.attribute_1;
formValues.attribute_2;
```

Because it will be a lot of this attributes, so I need something like:

```
var attributeValues = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   attributeValues += formValues.attribute_{i};
}
```

Or

```
var attributeValues = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var text = 'attribute' + i;
   attributeValues += formValues.text;
}
```

But no. Undefined is what I get :(.If anyone knows how to deal with this kind of stuff, help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Why are they separate properties instead of an array?

Comment: underscore symbol imposes the use of brackets notation

Comment: Separate properties are instead of an array because person who created this, thought it will be a good idea for some reason. I don't know who he is, or where can I find him and ask. :)

Comment: @GrafiCode no, underscore is fine for dot notation `obj.my_property = 1`. It's the dynamic nature of the property name that means it has to be using brackets.

Comment: Ok I solved it with formValues["attribute_" + i ]